# How to trim StringBuilder's string?

Tags: java, c#

How can we trim a `StringBuilder` value without the overhead caused by using `StringBuilder.toString().trim()` and thereby creating a new `String` and/or a new `StringBuilder` instance for each trim call?

Comment: May I ask why don't you want to use `StringBuilder.toString().trim()` ?

Comment: Actually i am in a loop where i have to compare this StringBuilder string with many other values so if i call StringBuilder.toString().trim() each time, it will create a new instance and i don't want to create a new String object each time.

Comment: You can use `toString().trim()` as many times as you need. Please edit your question and add your previous comment to clarify.

Comment: If it did have a `trim()` method there would presumably be questions asking why? Not a real question.

Comment: @EJP - How do I unlock this question ? I want to add the code to trim a StringBuilder.

Comment: I made some code to trim a StringBuilder, with test inputs to check the correctness - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212928/how-to-trim-a-java-stringbuilder/27417960#27417960

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Why does StringBuilder don't have trim() method

1. Because that's the way it was designed.  Try asking the designers<sup>1</sup>.
2. Because there is not much call for it.
3. Because the String `trim()` semantics and signature is a poor fit for mutable strings, though that is debatable.

Either way, the answer is not relevant to solving your problem.

> and how can we trim a StringBuilder value?

The simplest way is to use `StringBuilder.toString().trim()` ...

> I don't want to use StringBuilder.toString().trim().

In that case, so you need to do what `trim()` does under the covers: match and remove the leading and trailing white-space.  Since the `StringBuilder` API has no regex support, you'll need to do this that hard way; i.e. by iterating the characters from the front forward and end backward to see what characters need to be removed, etcetera.

*Are you sure* you wouldn't prefer to do it the easy way?  If not, this Q&A has some example implementations, analysis, benchmarking, etcetera:

- [How to trim a java stringbuilder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212928/how-to-trim-a-java-stringbuilder)

Finally, you could implement your own variation of the `StringBuilder` class that does have a `trim()` method.  You could possibly use a different internal representation so that operations that remove characters at the start don't copy characters.  (I would not recommend this ... but it is an option if you have a pragmatically strong need for `trim()`.)

---

> Actually i am in a loop where i have to compare this `StringBuilder` string with many other values so if i call `StringBuilder.toString().trim()` each time, it will create a new instance and i don't want to create a new String object each time.

The flip-side is that removing characters from the start of a `StringBuilder` entails copying all of the remaining characters.

Maybe you would be better off turning the complete `StringBuilder` into a `String` to start with, then when you use `trim()` and `substring()` and the like, you won't be copying characters<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - To the people who claim it is "not constructive" to say this, the alternative is to pretend that we *were* in the room when the design decisions were made and we *did* hear the debate that occurred.  But that would be a lie.  Frankly, it *is* constructive to point out that nobody here knows the answer, and not pretend otherwise.  Why?  Because a lot of readers will not be aware that the Java design processes at that time were opaque.</sup>

<sup>2 - Prior to Java 7, these methods work by creating a new String that *shares* the backing array of the original `String` ... so you only end up copying the string's control information.  In Java 7 they changed the implementation of `trim` and `substring` so that they used a String constructor that copies a subarray of the backing array.</sup>

Answer (score 6):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but if you're worried about performance perhaps you could perform the trim as you are appending to the StringBuilder.

`stringbuilder.append(string.trim())`

Answer (score 2):

> Why does StringBuilder don't have trim() method?

Hmm.. *`StringBuilder` is like `String`*, just a little difference that it can be modified after creation else it is same as string.

[StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

As stated in above link, *The principal operations on a StringBuilder are the append and insert methods*. I guess they are proposed to support mutable strings, same as with `StringBuffer`. And if you can get things done by a small call to some other method and then desired method then whats the matter. Why you want same implementation in multiple classes.

> How can we trim a StringBuilder value?

As said by others `stringBuilder.toString().trim();`

> I don't want to use `StringBuilder.toString().trim()`.

Hmm... matter of choice, any specific reason for this?

Comment: Actually i am in a loop where i have to compare this StringBuilder string with many other values so if i call StringBuilder.toString().trim() each time, it will create a new instance and i don't want to create a new String object each time

Comment: Use your own `char[]` and delimiters then. Check out `java.lang.String` code.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `StringBuilder` instance to `string` which later can be trimmed.

```
sb.toString().trim();//sb is stringBuilder Instance.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `StringBuilder.toString().trim()` but save it in a variable.

For example:

`String myTrimmedString = myStringBuilder.toString().trim();`

It doesn't have a `trim()` method because it is very easy and somewhat preferred to use immutable objects. Imagine one thread is trimming the `StringBuilder` while another is appending to it. Imagine the bugs and weirdness that could cause in your code.

Comment: Imagine one thread is trimming the StringBuilder while another is appending to it. 

This situation can also be occur in append operation while one thread is appending something and one is append something else... so what in that case? it should not support append as well

Comment: @PramodKumar I would imagine the VM only lets one thing write to the char[] at a time. However putting the same restriction on reads would be ridiculous. On a simultaneous read and write I would guess it blocks the read, making this a non-issue. It all depends on implementation of the VM. It is very possible trim() would work fine. It was a hypothetical situation to show how much easier it can be to implement immutable objects. And they use less memory.

Comment: Although your solution is correct, your justification is way off.  StringBuilder isn't thread-safe by design*, so, as Pramod Kumar said, **any** concurrent operation on it is dangerous.  Anyone who uses a StringBuilder in multiple threads without synchronizing on it needs shooting.  StringBuffer is the thread-safe version of StringBuilder, as it uses internal synchronization.  *(StringBuilder was introduced into Java for situations where you're certain only one thread will ever access it at a time and so wanted to do without the overhead of syncronization in StringBuffer.)